# Maven excludes a sole instance of the artifact

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven project `com.internal:prj`. Running (with latest maven 3.6.2):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.external
```

produces this:

```
[INFO] com.internal:prj:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.internal:library1:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO]    \- com.internal:library2:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO]       \- (com.external:library3:jar:4.4.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Why is the sole instance of `com.external:library3` being `omitted for duplicate`?

Answer (score 0):

For the `verbose` option of `dependency:tree`, the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) says:

"Notice this feature actually uses Maven 2 algorithm and may give wrong results when used with Maven 3"

Comment: Hm... That seems related, though packaging the project also does not include `com.external:library3` in the assembly. Using `dependency:tree` was just me trying to figure out what is going on. Could these be related somehow?

Comment: What does `dependency:tree` say when you leave out the `verbose` option?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.external:library3` gives no output. `mvn dependency:tree` lists `com.internal:library2:jar:3.3.3:compile` as the deepest dependency. IOW the output in both cases looks like as if `com.external:library3` was not a dependency of `com.internal:library2` at all. From the `-Dverbose` output you can see that that's not the case however.

Comment: Forget the `-Dverbose`. It is just rubbish. Go to the `pom.xml` of library2 and look up the dependency. Maybe it is `optional` or `provided`. There is some reason why it is not drawn transitively.

Comment: Checked that already, it's compile. Eclipse also sees it as compile. Very strange...

Comment: Could you post the relevant POMs, or snippets from them?